# pass own address while creating object in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-address

I am the following code

```
struct Me {
    Me(Me* a) { std::cout << "Processing " << a << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    Me a(&a);
    std::cout << "Created obj in " << &a << std::endl;
    Me* ak = new Me(ak);
    std::cout << "Created obj in " << ak << std::endl;
    delete ak;
    return 0;
}
```

and the output was

```
Processing 0x7ffdbd7f0607
Created obj in 0x7ffdbd7f0607
Processing 0x5653b66b5110
Created obj in 0x5653b6d35120
```

As you can observe that first 2 line of output was fine as the address passed to the constructor is same as the object being created but why can't same be done with dynamic creation. Can someone provide a description with possible solution for this?

Comment: This is precisely what `this` is for.... you don't need to invent tricks to try to get the address of the object executing a non-static member function. A good book or tutorial would explain this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Me a(&a);` it takes an address of uninitialised variable `a`. The address is valid, but the object at that address doesn't exists yet. The object is considered existing once the constructor function is entered.

In `Me* ak = new Me(ak);` `ak` is not initialized unit after `Me` constructor returns. That results in passing an indeterminate value of `ak` into `Me` constructor.

> Can someone provide a description with possible solution for this?

The solution for that is `this`:

```
struct Me {
    Me() { std::cout << "Processing " << this << std::endl; }
};
```

See [this pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) for full details.